# string.find a string in a dictionary in Lua

Tags: lua

So I have a dictionary:

```
local toFind = "Layla"

local songs = {
    {name = "Eric Clapton - Layla", id = "123"},
    {name = "Eric Clapton - I Shot The Sheriff", id = "321"}
}
```

Is it possible to use `string.find(songs, toFind)` or something similar to find the table that contains the "Layla" string?

Comment: `function find_song_by_name(songs, name) for _,v in ipairs(songs) do if string.find(v.name, name) then return v end end end`

Comment: @Nifim Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All strings have string functions attached as methods.
Therefore you can directly do...

```
for k,v in pairs(songs) do
 if v.name:find(toFind) then
  return songs[k], v.name
 end
end
```

...that returns the table and the full Text...

```
table: 0x565cbec0   Eric Clapton - Layla
```

Comment: Thank you very much.